# Why integrate to $\pi/2$ in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following problem to solve:

> $\large\mathbf{4.18}\;$ Given that $g(x)\geq 0$ has the property that $$\int g(x)\,dx=1,$$ show that $$f(x,y)=\frac{2g\big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\big)}{\pi\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\tag*{$x,y>0$}$$ is a pdf.

After I switch to polar coordinates I get the following expression

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2g(r)r}{\pi r}\,d\theta\,dr
$$ 
which obviously doesn't integrate to 1. If the limit of the inner integral is $\pi/2$ then the last expression integrates to $1$ like it's in the Solution Manual.

My question is, why do we integrate to $\pi/2$ and not $2\pi$ when we make a transformation to polar coordinates.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that $f$ is defined for $x, y>0$! You integrate from $0$ to $\pi/2$ in this case

Comment: @Jakobian So, if I x,y are taking half of the values on the real line, then r and the angle are taking half of their values on their domains?

Comment: Taking half of their values... no, I wouldn't say so. It's just that the first quadrant can be characterized in polar coordinates as points with angle between $0$ to $\pi/2$ and positive radius